# Recursion after 499-500 times of code running... why? All help appreciated. Novel web-scrape

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Using chrome 90 and python 3.9. All imports are fully updated as I just installed them.

As I have a bad ISP I made this script to copy novels from the internet to text files for offline viewing while my internet is out. This script pretty much works until the recursion error pops up then I have to manually go in and change the chapter after setting it. My expected results from the code is to run until the novel is completely copied (from chapter 1 to ######) to text files no matter how many chapters there is.

Always get a recursion error after I hit 499 or 500 chapters copied. I am not sure why it is this low nor how it even gets this error. I have read that recursion errors are usually after 999 iterations.

Error :: (first 2 lines repeat for quite a while)

```
  File "C:\Users\james\Documents\Novels\PEERLESS MARTIAL GOD\novel.py", line 42, in CopyChapter
    NextChapter()
  File "C:\Users\james\Documents\Novels\PEERLESS MARTIAL GOD\novel.py", line 49, in NextChapter
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(cLink)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 331, in begin
    self.headers = self.msg = parse_headers(self.fp)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 225, in parse_headers
    return email.parser.Parser(_class=_class).parsestr(hstring)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\parser.py", line 67, in parsestr
    return self.parse(StringIO(text), headersonly=headersonly)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\parser.py", line 56, in parse
    feedparser.feed(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 176, in feed
    self._call_parse()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 180, in _call_parse
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 295, in _parsegen
    if self._cur.get_content_maintype() == 'message':
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\message.py", line 594, in get_content_maintype
    ctype = self.get_content_type()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\message.py", line 578, in get_content_type
    value = self.get('content-type', missing)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\message.py", line 471, in get
    return self.policy.header_fetch_parse(k, v)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 316, in header_fetch_parse
    return self._sanitize_header(name, value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 287, in _sanitize_header
    if _has_surrogates(value):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\email\utils.py", line 57, in _has_surrogates
    s.encode()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Code ::

```
#! python3
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from unidecode import unidecode

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'C:\Program Files\Python39\chromedriver.exe'

NovelChapter = 'peerless-martial-god/chapter-1-spirit-awakening.html'
BaseURL = 'https://novelfull.com'
url = '%(U)s/%(N)s' % {'U': BaseURL, "N": NovelChapter}

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
driver.get(url)

def Close():
    driver.stop_client()
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

# start copy of chapter and add to a file
def CopyChapter():
    global soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    readables = soup.find(id='chapter-content')
    name = driver.title
    filename = name.replace('<',' ').replace('"',' ').replace('>',' ').replace('/',' ').replace("|",' ').replace("?",' ').replace("*",' ').replace(":", ' -').replace('Read ',"").replace(' online free from your Mobile, Table, PC... Novel Updates Daily ',"").replace(' online free - Novel Full',"")
    file_name = (filename + '.txt')
    print(file_name)
    data = ''
    for data in soup.find_all("p"):
        myfile = open(file_name, 'a+')
        myfile.write(unidecode(data.get_text())+'\n'+'\n')
        myfile.close()
    global lastURL
    lastURL = driver.current_url
    print('**********Chapter Copied!**********')
    NextChapter()
# end copy of chapter and add to a file

# start goto next chapter if exists then return to copy chapter else Close()
def NextChapter():
    bLink = soup.find(id = "next_chap")
    cLink = 'Next Chapter'
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(cLink)
    link.click()
    global currentURL
    currentURL = driver.current_url
    if currentURL != lastURL:
        CopyChapter()
    else:
        print('Finished!!!')
        Close()
# end goto next chapter if exists then return to copy chapter else Close()

CopyChapter()
#EOF
```

Comment: `NextChapter` calls `CopyChapter` and vice versa so each new chapter adds two new function calls to the stack. To solve this you could convert the recursive loop to a while loop avoiding the maximum recursion depth altogether.

Comment: This does work thank you. Took me awhile to get it all working properly using a few while loops to do various things. As well as a few for loops sprinkled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look as nice as defs but works perfectly for what I need. Added a few things such as making folders for the text files and starting from the chapter list page. There is probably a bunch of things that could be optimized but it works that is all that matters to me.

```
#! python3
import os
import requests
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from unidecode import unidecode

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'C:\Program Files\Python39\chromedriver.exe'

def Close():
    driver.stop_client()
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

global NovelName
NovelName = ['']
global DIR
global baseDIR
baseDIR = "C:/Users/james/Documents/Novels"
    
while NovelName:
    NN = NovelName.pop(-1)
    NNx = NN.replace('.html', '').replace('-', ' ').upper()
    DIR = '%(B)s/%(N)s' % {'B': baseDIR, "N": NNx}
    os.mkdir(DIR)

    BaseURL = 'https://novelfull.com'
    url = '%(U)s/%(N)s' % {'U': BaseURL, "N": NN}
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    print(url)
    global currentURL
    currentURL = driver.current_url
    global lastURL
    lastURL = ''
    
    soupx = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    ChapterList = soupx.find(id='list-chapter')
    CL = []
    for i in ChapterList.find_all("li"):
        CL.append(i)
    NovelChapter1Raw = CL[0]
    xx=[]
    for i in NovelChapter1Raw.find_all("a"):
        for x in i.find_all("span"):
            xx.append(x)
            ChapterTextX = ' '.join(map(str, xx))
    ChapterText = ChapterTextX.replace('<span class="chapter-text">','').replace('</span>','')
    BaseURL = 'https://novelfull.com'
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(ChapterText)
    url = '%(U)s/%(N)s' % {'U': BaseURL, "N": link}
    link.click()
    currentURL = driver.current_url

    while currentURL != lastURL:
        global soup
        soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        readables = soup.find(id='chapter-content')
        name = driver.title
        filename = name.replace('<',' ').replace('"',' ').replace('>',' ').replace('/',' ').replace("|",' ').replace("?",' ').replace("*",' ').replace(":", ' -').replace('Read ',"").replace(' online free from your Mobile, Table, PC... Novel Updates Daily ',"").replace(' online free - Novel Full',"")
        file_name = (filename + '.txt')
        print(file_name)
        data = ''
        for data in soup.find_all("p"):
            myfile = open(DIR +'/'+ file_name, 'a+')
            myfile.write(unidecode(data.get_text())+'\n'+'\n')
            myfile.close()
        lastURL = driver.current_url
        print('**********Chapter Copied!**********')
        bLink = soup.find(id = "next_chap")
        cLink = 'Next Chapter'
        link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(cLink)
        link.click()
        currentURL = driver.current_url
        
    print('Finished!!!')
    Close()
print('Finished!!!')
Close() #<- throws a bunch of errors but makes sure everything closes.

#EOF
```

Comment: Complete novel scrapper : https://github.com/hanziwolf33/Multiple-Novel-Scapper               Didn't have any major issues while running it except for my internet messing up.